# How to auto-submit a Drupal webform?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I am using [Drupal webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform) and wonder whether it's possible to auto-submit a Webform?

Since Webform comes with `%get[key]` to fill the form fields by default values from a FORM GET URL, and so I'd like to save the user a submit button click. Possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a [Drupal behavior](http://drupal.org/node/205296) in Javascript that applies some kind of logic to the check the form elements (i.e., submit once fields x, y, and z are filled in by the user).  Because Drupal uses the jQuery form plugin, you can background submit the form with [ajaxSubmit](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#api) or simply [trigger the form's submit event](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on David Eads' answer, using jQuery without Ajax, by pressing Enter:

```
  jQuery('#my-form .my-form-item input')
    .keypress(function(e) {
      if (e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery('#my-form').submit();
      }
    });
```